# I want grep to grep one word which is having spaces it

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I would like to grep the word **“s a i”** (which has spaces in it)  in a `xyz.txt` file  which is saved in another directory. I tried to find an answer but I didn’t manage to find any. I have to use the `grep` command only.

Comment: There is zero problems grepping with spaces. There is a possible problem passing an argument with spaces in shell. Until you provide an examples and errors you encounter, it is hard to tell what answer should look like.

Comment: Just in case it helps the next person - I was searching for two words as well and found that the second word was not capitalized as I'd expected.  Something else to double check if you've landed here like me.

Answer (score 6):

You can escape the space with a backslash:

```
grep My\ Documents
```

Answer (score 5):

Just add quotes around your `grep` command:

```
grep "s a i" "another directory/xyz.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression:-

```
grep -E "(s a i)" a.txt
```